# React js Spotify API request failed with status code 400

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, spotify-app

I'm trying to pull some data using react js, axios and the Spotify API. When the user logs in, an access token is grabbed through the URL, but whenever I try to grab data through one of the API's endpoint, it gives me a status 400. It was working before but now it doesn't.

```
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState()
    const [token, setToken] = useState("")
    const navigate = useNavigate()

  useEffect(() => {
    const hash = window.location.hash
    let token = window.localStorage.getItem("token")

    if(!token && hash){
      token = hash.substring(1).split("&").find(elem => elem.startsWith("access_token")).split("=")[1]

      window.location.hash = ""
      window.localStorage.setItem("token", token)
    }

    setToken(token)
  }, [])

  const logout = () => {
    setToken("")
    window.localStorage.removeItem("token")
    navigate("/")

  }


  useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me", {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            },
          }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)
            setProfile(response.data)
          })

  }, [])
```

I do realise this has nothing to do with axios and more to do with the API itself but I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: if it was working and now isn't, you've probably hit a rate limit. have you tried logging the token and seeing if it's being set correctly / isn't expired?

Comment: @Insula Yh, I've even created a new app in the spotify developer dashboard and used a new client id

Comment: I would console log the error.response.data and see if there's anything in there, it will most likely be a rate limit, you could try again in a few hours and see if it's still not working. try this: 

 `.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.response.data); // Log the error response to see more details
}); `

Comment: @Insula When I console the error it says  "only valid bear authentication supported"

Comment: ahh okay, so that typically means there's a problem with a way you're sending the token in your request. I'd do a bunch of console logging to see if the token is actually okay, the Bearer ${token} could be undefined or null. I'd also log the localstorage token as well as the token in useEffect and go from there